# Is it possible to dynamically span columns in a QGridLayout?

Tags: pyqt5, qgridlayout

I am using PyQt5, and have a need to create a grid layout, initially with fixed sizes of rows and columns.
At some point, I will have QLabel (or QButton) text that will be larger than the default cell width.
Is it possible to adjust the size of the grid cell dynamically?
At this point, I don't have any test code because I'm still trying to visualize how this can be accomplished - I'm just unsure if this is possible or not.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You talk about "fixed sizes of rows and columns", but that's ambiguous: are you talking about the row/column *count* or the geometry of each cell? QGridLayout doesn't allow to set fixed sizes, only *minimum* widths (for for columns) or heights (for rows). I suggest you to try to make your question more clear, but also take your time with Designer in order to better understand basics aspects of layout managers.

Comment: @musicamante: my apologies for not expressing myself clearly.

Comment: @musicamante: my apologies for not expressing myself clearly.  I meant that when I initially create a layout with QGridLayout, I get cells as I expect, and each cell has the same geometry,  i.e. a certain number of x/y pixels.  This is as I would expect.  Somewhere in the logic (driven by a properties file I plan on using) it is possible that the widget I assign to a cell takes up more space than initially allocated to that cell.  BTW, this would happen only to column 0, so I thought of using minimumWidth for column 0 only when I initially configure the grid.  Is there a better way?  Thanks.

Comment: A layout gives the amount of space to a widget based on that widget's [`sizeHint()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop), considering its [`minimumSizeHint()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSizeHint-prop) and deciding the correct proportions based on its [`sizePolicy()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop). If you see the same sizes, it's only because you're probably using similar (or identical) widgets. If any of those widgets then has a change that affects any of the properties above, then the layout manager will automatically compute geometries accordingly.

Comment: Layouts are not static: every change in the inner widgets (or the geometry of the widget they're set) will adapt and make fit everything as best as possible. Sorry, but you cannot try "to visualize how this can be accomplished", if you don't know yet how layout management works. Other than what said above (experiment with Designer), I also suggest you to make some simple tests from code, using different widgets (or same widgets with different properties, for example with some QLabels that have different text lengths), so that you can begin to understand how layout of widget works.

Comment: Note that, based on your comment, what you want to know and understand has nothing to do about spanning, which involves the amount of horizontal and/or vertical cells of the layout an item eventually takes. Cells coordinates (rows, columns) in grid layouts do not refer to actual pixel sizes, they are logical indexes, similarly to arrays or list of lists: if you put a widget in cell `0, 0` (row, column), another in cell `0, 10`, and don't add other widgets, you'll have **exactly** the same result you'd have if you put the second at `0, 1`.